# Delete strings between given two pattern using SED excluding matching pattern

Tags: sed

I am just started learning used of SED and I want to delete strings between given two pattern excluding the second pattern matching.

In Details:
Assume We are having string in file:

```
Name Rohit
   profession = student
   place = bangalore
   like = game
Name Ravi
   profession = working
   place = chennai
   like = xyz
```

If I have provided Name Rohit value then I have to delete all the information available for Rohit.

for input = Rohit

output will be:

```
Name Ravi
   profession = working
   place = chennai
   like = xyz
```

I tried below sed command:

```
 sed "/^\s*Name Rohit/,/^\s*Name/d" del.txt
```

and Name of another person is also getting deleted as below:

```
profession = working
place = chennai
like = xyz
```

Can anyone here help me resolved this issue. Thanks in advance!